# Powershell in jenkins: ConvertTo-WebApplication : Path doesn't belong to 'WebAdministration' provider

Tags: powershell, jenkins, iis

I'm trying to execute a powershell script in a jenkinsfile ( to convert a specific path in iis to application -- similar to the gui command "Convert to Application"

powershell 'ConvertTo-WebApplication -PSPath "${websitePath}"'

but unfortuantely i'm getting this error:

Running PowerShell script
powershell.exe : ConvertTo-WebApplication : Path doesn't belong to 'WebAdministration' provider.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: assuming websitePath is Jenkins parameter - You should pass it to powershell script as `ConvertTo-WebApplication -PSPath $env:websitePath` as for batch script and powershell jenkins creates environment variables with parameter values

Comment: thanks @tomek; the websitePath is a variable I defined in the script
def websitePath = 'IIS:\\Sites\\Default Web Site\\MyApp'

I'm getting this error now: 
CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following 
error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 
(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: What are the commands you put in `jenkinsfile`? You can call `ConvertTo-WebApplication` from the middle of nowhere, as it requires a valid virtual directory to be created/queried as input (see the [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/convertto-webapplication?view=winserver2012-ps#examples)).